# Filtering Objects Based On Another Model

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-views

I have a website where service providers upload their services to the site and in addition to their services they can also upload the FAQ for each service they create.

So I have two models for this each separate and linked with a Foreign Key.

below is my `model.py` file with these two models

```
class Services(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, max_length=130)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    pricing = models.IntegerField()
    detail = SummernoteTextField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='services')
    author  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class FAQ(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="The possible question that a client could ask you")
    answer = models.TextField(help_text="The response to the question above")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Services, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='faq_service', help_text="Which service is this FAQ linked to?")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Within my `views.py` I have added the capabilities that allow me to display a ListView to of the FAQ within the same DetailView which contains all details of the post.
My `views.py` for that looks like this:

```
class ServiceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Services

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServiceDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['faq'] = FAQ.objects.all() # to fix-->Need to only show FAQ of that service 
        return context
```

Now, I need to be able to **Filter** the FAQ section basing on the FAQ for that Service which has been listed only. I am not sure how to do this. I tried visiting the Docs but there no solution for a scenarios like this and I do not want to add the FAQ to the Services Model because I need the Service providers to be able to list as many FAQ's as they want.

In case anyone wants to know what my template which displays this looks like, here it is

```
<h3 class="mt-4 mb-4">Service FAQ</h3>

<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  {% for faq in faq %}
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button
        class="accordion-button collapsed"
        type="button"
        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
        data-mdb-target="#flush-collapseOne{{ faq.id }}"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="flush-collapseOne"
      >
        {{ faq.question }}
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div
      id="flush-collapseOne{{ faq.id }}"
      class="accordion-collapse collapse"
      aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"
      data-mdb-parent="#accordionFlushExample"
    >
      <div class="accordion-body">
        {{ faq.answer }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter the `service` field such that it is equal to `self.object`. In most views that inherit from the [**`SingleObjectMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin), one of the first steps is to attach an `object` attribute to the view object:

```
class ServiceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Services

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['faq'] = FAQ.objects.filter(
            service=self.object
        )
        return context
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Service` instead of <s>`Services`</s>.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I guess I really need to revisit the documentation and get to understand `self`. It worked the exact way I wanted it to. Thanks once again.